# How to set username for PushOk SCC plugin for Git?

Tags: git, version-control

We have recently started using Git as Source Control provider, and for our PowerBuilder source code we use the PushOk Git SCC proxy. It works fine to get lastest, check out and commit files . But we always get an unknown user name for these commits when we push it to GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution. I had to add two config values to PushOk gitconfig file located under the path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Pushok Software\GITSCC\GIT\etc\gitconfig

```
[user]
    name = "myusername"
    email = "me@domain.net"
```